# Cloning data - ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, clone, ngrx

I am trying to clone data from NGRX store so i can edit them.

Declarations

```
public stuff$: Observable<StuffModel> | undefined;
public editableStuff$: Observable<StuffModel> | undefined;
```

TS

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.editableStuff$ = Object.assign(
      {},
      (this.stuff$ = .........
          id === 'newStuff'
            ? of(this.newStuff)
            : this.store.pipe(
                ...............
                select((entities) => entities[id] ?? ({} as StuffModel))
              )
        )
      ))
    );
  }
```

HTML

```
<ng-container *ngIf="editableStuff$ | async as stuff">
...
<input
          matInput
          placeholder="Stuff"
          [(ngModel)]="stuff.stuffName"
        />
```

Problems is that i am getting error `ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'` and dont know why. When i use `<ng-container *ngIf="stuff$ | async as stuff">` it works but how can i make it work with editableStuff$? When i console log bot variables `stuff$` and `editabelStuff$` with `JSON.stringify()` they are same.

Comment: You are using `Object.assign`, so I don't why you expect it to be an observable? Object assign creates an object, not an observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Object.assign`, that creates an object, so what you have now, is an object **containing** an observable. If you want to make a copy of an observable, a `map` should suffice, so something like this (simplified):

```
this.editableStuff$ = this.stuff$.pipe(
  map(item => ({ ...item }))
);
```

Where we use the spread operator to copy the item.

Comment: I have just one question if u have time. If i use `this.editableStuff = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.stuff$));` but editableStuff is not observable and i remove async from html it wont work and gives me just empty fields do you know why?

Comment: But `this.stuff$` is an observable right? You won't get value of the observable by doing that. You need to somehow subscribe to an observable... using `subscribe` or the `async` pipe.

Comment: To clarify, What you are doing right now mentioned in comment, is stringifying and parsing a **Subscription**, not the observable value.